# Implementing a required as_view argument in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a few views in my application which require a keyword argument to be passed to `as_view` to function as such:

```
url(r'^api/foobar/$',
    FoobarView.as_view(key='foobar'),
    name='foobar'),
```

The view itself uses the key in a way similar to this:

```
class FoobarView(APIView):
    key = None

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({
            'foobar': self.key
        })
```

What's the best way to ensure that the `key` keyword argument is passed to `as_view` and trigger an error if it wasn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, in your view overridde the as_view an check if set.

Something like this:

```
class FoobarView(APIView):
    key = None

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({
            'foobar': self.key
        })

    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):

        if 'key' not in initkwargs:
            raise ValueError

        return super().as_view(**initkwargs)
```

Just decide yourself what exactly you want to do if key is missing.